# requestPermission() doesn't fully recreate the activity stack

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have activity A that launches activity B. This activity then requests `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. On Android 6.0, this brings up the permission dialog (which immediately destroys activity B as soon as the dialog pops up). However, whatever the user picks, the system will then return to activity A.

Requesting other permissions works fine in other places, but I suppose the external storage permissions are some of those that, as the docs warn, "require a restart of the application", and "the system will recreate the activity stack".

My problem is that activity B is never recreated, let alone `onRequestPermissionsResult` being called. I would have thought "recreating the activity stack" involves launching activity B again, and ideally `onRequestPermissionResult` being called on it. How am I supposed to handle this?

Comment: "which immediately destroys activity B as soon as the dialog pops up" -- this sounds weird to me. Activity B should be paused and maybe stopped at that point, but not destroyed. Are you sure you're not calling `finish()` or using some property like `noHistory`?

Comment: @SnildDolkow - yes, the one place where `finish()` is called has a `Log`, which doesn't get called, and I'm not using properties on the activity. I'll double-check, but both `onPause` and `onDestroy` get called, and IIRC `onDestroy` shows up immediately - the background of the permission dialog is black too. This is only in this activity that's using `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, the other ones are fine.

Comment: @SnildDolkow - you're right, I double-checked, and this activity has `noHistory` due to antique reasons that I completely forgot about. I'm ready for the dunce cap.

Comment: Wow, lucky guess! Glad it worked out. :)

Comment: @SnildDolkow - I'm torn, I could delete the question, or ask you to write this as an answer. I think the latter would be best, there may be other people making the same dumb mistake.

Comment: Sure. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> which immediately destroys activity B as soon as the dialog pops up

That sounds weird to me. Activity B should be paused (and maybe stopped) at that point, but not *destroyed*. Are you sure you're not calling `finish()` or using some property like [`noHistory`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist)?

You may be able to find some clues as to why your activity is being destroyed in the `am_finish_activity` and/or `am_destroy_activity` print in the event log. Example from me leaving Gmail with the BACK button (notice the `app-request` and `finish-imm` reasons):

```
$ adb logcat -bevents
I/am_finish_activity( 1155): [0,947820256,3228,com.google.android.gm/.ConversationListActivityGmail,app-request]
I/am_pause_activity( 1155): [0,947820256,com.google.android.gm/.ConversationListActivityGmail]
I/am_on_paused_called(17619): [0,com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivityGmail]
I/am_home_stack_moved( 1155): [0,1,0,0,prevFinished]
I/wm_task_moved( 1155): [3162,1,1]
I/am_focused_activity( 1155): [0,com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher]
I/am_resume_activity( 1155): [0,285205047,3162,com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher]
I/am_on_resume_called(24956): [0,com.android.launcher2.Launcher]
I/am_destroy_activity( 1155): [0,947820256,3228,com.google.android.gm/.ConversationListActivityGmail,finish-imm]
```

Not sure how detailed those reason strings get, but if you're really having a hard time figuring it out, it's worth a look.

Comment: Yep, `noHistory` is the culprit, and I'm a schmuck.